# how to add a character variable to character array in c++

Tags: c++

I want to write the C++ code that can help me to give the drive letter which contains the given folder. I am writing the given code and getting the error while adding the character variable to a string variable at line 11.
Can anyone help me out in rectifying the below code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Shlwapi.h"
int main()
{
    char var;
    for (var = 'A'; var <= 'Z'; ++var)
    {
        char buffer_1[] = var +":\\PerfLogs";      ------->>>> line where i am getting the error
        char *lpStr1;
        lpStr1 = buffer_1;
        int retval;
        retval = PathFileExists(lpStr1);
        if (retval == 1)
        {
            std :: cout << "Search for the file path of : " << lpStr1;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `std::string`

Comment: You can't initialize arrays at run-time, they must be initialized at compile-time. But since you are programming in C++ there a very easy solution to your problem: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: `retval = PathFileExists((var + std::string(":\\PerfLogs")).c_str());`. Alternatively, `char buffer[] = "*:\\PerLogs"; buffer[0] = var; retval = PathFileExists(buffer);`

Comment: Also note that your loop is not portable. Not all systems have character encodings where all letters are contiguous.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It's a pretty safe bet that all systems **with drive letters A-Z** have them contiguously.

Comment: Thanks, it worked !!!

Comment: @MSalters: Pretty safe bet = satellites crashing down on planets. It's clearer IMHO to make the solution portable, as I do.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Let me rephrase it in a different way,then. **Drive letters** are already not portable. `std::file_system` has an abstract notion of root names, but their exact syntax is wholly unspecified by C++. The only thing you know is that they're represented as strings, and there's no way you can portably enumerate these strings.

Comment: @Bathsheba: `#include <windows.h>`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the string library:

```
std::string str1="Str 1";
std::string str2=" Str 2";
str1.append(str2);      //str1 = "Str 1 Str 2"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, its working fine over there but then I am not able to convert the same to char* type and i need to do that for accessing PathFileExists(lpStr1) function, any idea about that

Comment: @PuneetGarg `PathFileExists(your_string.c_str())`

Answer (score 2):

The specific compiler error you get is due to your attempting to add a `const char*` type (as a result of a string literal decayed to a pointer type) to a `char`. Let's not worry too much about that; rather, let's put the C++ standard library to good use:

A *portable* solution would be as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// ToDo - include the header for PathFileExists
using namespace std::string_literals; // Bring in the std::string user defined literal.

int main() {
    for (auto c : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"s){ // Note the user defined literal.
        std::string path = c + ":\\PerfLogs"s; // And again. This calls an overloaded `+`.
        int retval = PathFileExists(path.c_str()); // Pass the char buffer.
        if (retval == 1){
            std::cout << "Search for the file path of : " << path;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing `using namespace std::string_literals;` and [`PathFileExists` is declared in `Shlwapi.h`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @O'Neil: On your first point, doesn't the string header bring that in? On the second point, no matter as there's nothing in the question to really point out which file system library they are using.

Comment: 1) No it doesn't. 2) Except the #include of that file.

Comment: @Bathsheba thanks, It worked, and yes there is the need to use the namespace to define user define literals... thanks a lot everyone for your help.

Comment: @O'Neil: Checked the first point, and yes, as you knew all along, you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::string` for this as others have suggested. But since it's just 1 character it wouldn't be too hard to do this:

```
const char buffer_1[] = { var, ':', '\\', 'P', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'L', 'o', 'g', 's', '\0' };
```